# Is there a known MLE for the numerator df of a sample of F statistics?

Tags: maximum-likelihood, degrees-of-freedom, f-distribution

Suppose you have observations $f_1, f_2, \ldots, f_n$ which are drawn *i.i.d.* from a central F distribution, with unknown numerator degrees of freedom, $n_1$ and known denominator degrees of freedom, $n_2$. What is the preferred method for computing/estimating the MLE of $n_1$?  If the likelihood is known to be concave as a function of $n_1$ (I would guess it is, but am not certain), I could just use a numerical method like golden section search. Is there anything better?

I am aware of [Spruill's method](http://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/0047259X86900709) for ML estimation of the non-centrality parameter when the $f_i$ are noncentral, and $n_1$ and $n_2$ are known. It appears to use the transformation 
$$w_i = \frac{f_i}{n_2/n_1 + f_i}$$
Is this a standard transformation for F distributed RVs that might be applicable to this problem, or just a red herring?

Comment: The $F$ distribution has some nice monotonicity properties associated with it. If you want, you can look at [this question and answer](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/26632/monotonic-behavior-of-a-function/26649#26649). I'm not quite sure the paper there will be immediately relevant to your problem, though.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It doesn't look like there could be a closed form solution for it, but it would be easy to derive numerically.  An advantage of having a single parameter is that you can easily plot the likelihood.  How you go about finding the MLE depends on whether you're doing it just once for a particular data set or whether you plan to continually do it.  If I were doing it just once, I'd first plot the log likelihood and then use some generic optimizer, like `optimize` in R [[see manual page](http://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-patched/library/stats/html/optimize.html)].